# How to calculate relative frequency for each cell of a data.frame in relation to a second data.frame?

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

[…]
How do I calculate relative Frequency for each cell of `data_foobar`, in relation to `data_baseline` (=100%)? Both contain absolute count of articles, by year, but `data_foobar` only contains years with values > 0.

sample data (updated):

```
data_baseline <- structure(list(Year = 2010:2014, `Area Studies` = c(3636L, 4247L, 
3922L, 2050L, 201L), Arts = c(2082L, 1993L, 1859L, 974L, 87L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Area Studies", "Arts"), row.names = 111:115, class = "data.frame")

data_foobar <- structure(list(Year = 2011:2014, `Area Studies` = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
NA), Arts = c(5L, 8L, 3L, NA)), .Names = c("Year", "Area Studies", 
"Arts"), row.names = c("58", "59", "60", "61"), class = "data.frame")
```

How would it be done with plyr/dplyr?

Comment: Most of what you've written here is not necessary for the question. I reckon that you can safely delete everything before "How do I..."

Answer (score 4):

The would give you (in percentage form) the relative frequency of data_foobar". The [-1] removes the Year col from the element-wise division operation

```
> cbind(data_foobar[1], 100*data_foobar[-1]/data_baseline[-1])
   Year Area Studies      Arts
57 2010   0.02750275 0.2881844
58 2011   0.02354603 0.2508781
59 2012   0.05099439 0.4303389
60 2013   0.09756098 0.3080082
61 2014           NA        NA
```

If your data were not so "regular" and there were a mismatch of col names you might need to use `intersect(names(data_baseline), names(data_foobar) )[-1]` as the column selector vector.

For the modified problem:

```
cbind(data_foobar[1], 
      100*data_foobar[ data_foobar$Year %in% data_baseline$Year, -1]/
           data_baseline[ data_foobar$Year %in% data_baseline$Year, -1 ])

   Year Area Studies      Arts
57 2010   0.02750275 0.2881844
58 2011   0.02354603 0.2508781
59 2012   0.05099439 0.4303389
60 2013   0.09756098 0.3080082
61 2014           NA        NA
```

That uses logical indexing to select only those years that are shared in both Year-columns

Comment: This seems like a nice simple solution, unfortunately the real data frame has missing years, resulting in an error `/ only defined for equally-sized data frames` . BTW, the given intersect command also throws `Error in !"Year" : invalid argument type` ?

Comment: I obviously failed to test the intersection code. Try: `intersect(names(data_baseline), names(data_foobar) )[-1]`. You _should_ post sample datasets with the same complexity as your real problem.